# Android Studio error: Cannot load project

Tags: android

I have this error in Android Studio:

> Cannot load project: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: org/jetbrains/android/uipreview/AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager [Plugin: org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.dsl]

Answer (score 9):

Just uninstall anko plugin It worked for me

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that you have a **plugin** which is **incompatible** with the IDE.
In my case it was Gradle GUI, and in your case it's `Plugin: org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.dsl`.
Just simply uninstall it from Plugins in settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
open plugin and type anko then uninstall .
```

if it not there and you still have this issue uninstall android studio and
 download android studio 2.1.3 until we find solution .